# How to increment a string with a custom character set

Tags: php, string, numbers

Given a custom alphabet like `['f', 'h', 'z', '@', 's']`

I'd like to take a string written in this "alphabet" like

`ffff@zz` and increment it

So for example if the string was `sss` After incrementing it will look like `hfff` the same way that if you increment `999` you get `1000`

My current attempt is here: https://3v4l.org/FjAsd

Given:

```php
$characters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$string = 'cccc';
```

my code can do:

```
baaaa
```

but if give it

```
$characters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$string = 'aaa';
```

it will return
`b`

When I expected `aab`

Comment: In this particular case you can replace letters with numbers, do regular math, then replace numbers with letters. As soon as you get letters' count more than 10 - you have to use a new number system.

Comment: I think the problem with my implementation is base_convert() treats "0" and "000" as equivalent so "aab" and "b" get treated as equivalent?

Comment: indexing characters by 1 appears to introduce other bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this works is by processing the string from the end, each time you look at a character you check it's position in the array (I use a flipped array as it's more efficient than using `array_search()` each time).  Then if the character is at the end of the array, then set it to the 0th element of the alphabet and increment the next digit to the left.  If there is another letter from the alphabet to increment the current value, then just replace it and stop the loop.

The last bit is that if you have processed every character and the loop was still going, then there is a carry - so add the 0th digit to the start.

```
$characters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$string = 'cccc';

$index = array_flip($characters);
$alphabetCount = count($index)-1;
for ( $i = strlen($string)-1; $i >= 0; $i--)  {
    $current = $index[$string[$i]]+1;
    // Carry
    if ( $current > $alphabetCount )  {
        $string[$i] = $characters[0];
    }
    else    {
        // update and exit
        $string[$i] = $characters[$current];
        break;
    }
}
// As reached end of loop - carry
if ( $i == -1 ) {
    $string = $characters[0].$string;
}
echo $string;
```

gives

```
aaaaa
```

with

```
$characters = ['f', 'h', 'z', '@', 's'];
$string = 'ffff@zz';
```

you get

```
ffff@z@
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with something like this:

```php
$string = 'ccc';
$alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$numbers = array_keys($alphabet);
$numeric = str_replace($alphabet, $numbers, $string);
$base = count($alphabet) + 1;
$decimal = base_convert($numeric, $base, 10);
$string = base_convert(++$decimal, 10, $base);
strlen($decimal) !== strlen($string)
   and $string = str_replace('0', '1', $string);
echo str_replace($numbers, $alphabet, $string);
```

This one has the advantage of supporting multi byte characters